# Tomcat Tutorial: Why Did This Install Fail?

Tags: java, tomcat, ant

I am working through the Tomcat tutorial [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/appdev/index.html) and in particular [the section of installing the hello world war file to the server container](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/appdev/processes.html#Test_Your_Web_Application)

Upon ant install I get this error:

```
BUILD FAILED
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: http://localhost:8080/manager/text/deploy?path=%2Ftomcat-tutorial&war=file%3A%2F%2F%2Fhome%2Fdavid%2FIdeaProjects%2Ftomcat-tutorial%2Fbuild
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1626)
at org.apache.catalina.ant.AbstractCatalinaTask.execute(AbstractCatalinaTask.java:230)
at org.apache.catalina.ant.DeployTask.execute(DeployTask.java:196)
at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:288)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:357)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:385)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1337)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1306)
at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1189)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:758)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:217)
at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:257)
at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:104)
```

This is using both the [example web.xml](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/appdev/web.xml.txt) and the [example build.xml](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/appdev/build.xml.txt) provided on the Tomcat site.  Why is this failing and how do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTP 401 is Unauthorized. You haven't configured/used the correct credentials.

So it's not bulding that fails, it's the post-build step trying to deploy your application.

Maybe you did not follow [this instruction for ant file](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/appdev/build.xml.txt):

> - Create a "build.properties" file in your application's top-level
>     source directory (or your user login home directory) that defines
>     appropriate values for the "manager.password", "manager.url", and
>     "manager.username" properties described above.

Edit: [This](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/manager-howto.html) might be of help:

> You can find the role names in the web.xml file of the Manager web
>   application. The available roles are:
>
> ```
> manager-gui — Access to the HTML interface.
> manager-status — Access to the "Server Status" page only.
> manager-script — Access to the tools-friendly plain text interface that is described in this document, and to the "Server Status" page.
> manager-jmx — Access to JMX proxy interface and to the "Server Status" page.
> ```

Comment: I actually did, here is the contents of build.properties: `manager.username=manager
manager.password=manager`  I however did not set up some kind of stateful Realm.  There were no instructions on that :(

Comment: `Define one or more Tomcat users. The Manager web application runs under a security constraint that requires a user to be logged in, and have the security role manager-script assigned to him or her. How such users are defined depends on which Realm you have configured in Tomcat's conf/server.xml file -- see the Realm Configuration HOW-TO for more information. You may define any number of users (with any username and password that you like) with the manager-script role. `

Comment: I also added the manager username and password to the tomcat-users.xml and restarted the server, but that had no effect `<user username="manager" password="manager" roles="manager"/>`

Comment: @user3220334 did you test that you can manually log in with those credentials?

Comment: @user3220334 I don't think manager is a valid role in tomcat 7. See my update.

Comment: Im just in the beginning steps of the tutorial, so no.  But on the mailing list they say I need to run a security manager script, but not sure where that is

Comment: Got it, thanks for the different roles names and descriptions!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the solution is to make the role "manager-script" in the tomcat-users.xml.  Which is terribly unclear, but so be it.  That makes it sound like a script that needs to be run.

```
  <user username="manager" password="manager" roles="manager-script"/>
```